# KQL make_set or make_list on rows into columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a basic query in Defender

```
DeviceInfo
| join DeviceNetworkInfo on DeviceId
| project DeviceId,NetworkAdapterType,IPAddresses
```

The result is a lot of repeating rows, I want to move this ---
[image]

To something like this --
[image]

Basically, I wanted to see if could "distinct" a column and roll up other columns into lists or arrays using make_set or make_list?  I wasn't sure if this was possible... thanks!!!

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Below is the example **`kql`** query which worked for me:

```
datatable(ID:int, DEPT:string, ADDRESS:dynamic)
[
    8, "CSE", dynamic([1.2, "Rithwik"]),
    8, "CSE", dynamic([1.3, "hello"]),
    8, "ECE", dynamic([1.4, "Bojja"])
]
| summarize dep = make_set(DEPT), ipadress = make_list(ADDRESS) by ID
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleMetrics?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WPPQvCMBRF9/yKR6cEguDHIAUHbTJ0k9atFElNsGmTtjQRqfjjjVAHBd/dzj3DfVL4kMoonLJYd54C48dT7PyouyuFPWMZz/NYTp2w%20kJQgSDclkKU5DyiMBe4WC5WAWba13fdRiWh/8V1gLUypv/SePKjbQI89E0jgoZK9AR3s1aM%20qFAqgF2YEWrzk55/J5MKOhByFE596mMdh7PHxCoJkjZCwBydEfvAAAA)

For your query you can integrate from summarize statement.

```
DeviceInfo
| join DeviceNetworkInfo on DeviceId
| project DeviceId,NetworkAdapterType,IPAddresses
| summarize dep = make_set(NetworkAdapterType), ipadress = make_list(IPAddresses) by DeviceId
```